# Which SQL Server message is spelled correctly?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, spelling

Which SQL Server 2008 message is spelled correctly?

[image]

Comment: Try asking this on english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't you own a copy of Microsoft Word?

Comment: Good spot but not realy rellevant [sic]

Comment: I vote for both. But I'm a Swede so what do I know.

Comment: Canceled is American English and Cancelled is British or Canadian English according to here http://www.oes.org/page2/11255~Cancelled_or_Canceled.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both technically correct spelling.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canceled

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable according to: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cancel), [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cancel), [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary?langpair=en|en&q=cancel&hl=en&aq=f)

Answer (score 0):

Cancelled is the correct way to spell it (or at least the most popular one), although canceled is, albeit partially, somewhat accepted. My recommendation is to always use cancelled.